# return field value when clicking on pivot table sub form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have an Access 2007 form with a pivot table subform. I have an onclick event for one of the fields in the table in the subform to fire an event. Works in datasheet view, but not in pivottable view. The event doesn't fire at all in pivot table view. How do i pull this off?

Comment: This maybe a limitation in Access. I found something that may or may not work for so I won't post it as an answer. You can try use the "Form_Click" callback to accomplish the logic you are trying to implement. Ref: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e2ef0e84-8679-480b-82e2-cca06b55a11d/access-pivot-table-click-event?forum=accessdev

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I had tried that... the event fires, however The value it returns for the field is always the first in the recordsource not the record i click on like I'm trying to do.